# Replacing rotted shed flooring without changing foundation

Tags: flooring, shed

I realised recently that part of my shed floor had sunk. When I pulled up the carpet I found that the wooden floor had rotted away. After pulling away some of the rotted wood it looks (to me) as though the underlying support is still in tact.

I don't know how old the shed is. The property is around 20 years old, so the shed will be less than that.

**My question is - to fix this can I simply rip up the rotted wood on top and replace it with new wood?**

See below 2 pictures to help explaining. The orange dot in the 1st picture indicates the placement of the shot in the 2nd picture.

The purple speech bubbles indicate what I believe to be support beams just from where the wood lines up and the sound made when knocking the floor.

[image: Rotted wooden floor]
[image: Hole macro]

---

**Edit**

Below is an image the shows the interior wall as well as the issue.

[image: Wall and floor shot]

Comment: nice pictures and description. Can you get a photo of the outside wall where this damage is? You can certainly cut out the floor and put new plywood down over existing supports, or toe in some mew supports for the chunk you replace but you are going to want to remove the water source and perhaps it is rotted outside too

Comment: Thank you for the response and advice. I've added an image I took which includes the interior wall but it's dark now so I can't get one of the outside unfortunately! 

To describe the outside though - that wall, and 2 other walls, sit directly against a gravel pathway. So looking at that picture again I can imagine that if I take up the carpet around the remaining walls - that wood may also be rotten! 

So when I put down the new flooring I will see if there is something I can use to seal it off in some way. Otherwise like you and Jack imply - it will happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can simply replace the plywood floor, but you really need to investigate why it rotted to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post to include a picture due to the comment from noybman. I think possibly there's not adequate protection between the ground outside and those planks. As there's no damp on the tarp underneath and the damp appears to spread from the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rip up the rotted wood and replace it. Make sure you check your joists too though, because they may be beginning to rot also. Once you have all of the rotten wood gone, spray down all of your joists with killz to protect them from rotting out. Also, it might be a good idea to lay some plastic down on top of your joists before installing the new sub floor. This will act as a moisture barrier for your new wood. Good luck.